# Show hints in quiz app in Meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, meteor

In Meteor, I have a quiz.

Each question has multiple hints.

How can I release one hint at a time when the user asks for another hint?

I guess I should store the hints as an array to each question, but I only want to show one a a time, so it's not possible to just show the entire array.

I don't know if it's best if the hint array holds objects

```
{ text: 'The hint text', isShownToUsers: ['userId1', 'userId2'] }
```

I'm afraid the `isShownToUsers` array will become very big, and I will have to subscribe to the entire array every time I show a question to a user.

But maybe it is also good that it's saved which hints are shown to the user, so the user will see the same hints if he/she comes back to the question?

Comment: I've not used meteor but here's an idea.  I'm guessing each user connects to the quiz via web sockets (from what I've read on meteor it is a socket based platform right?).  If this is the case, you could set a property on the connected user socket `hasHintAtIndex: 0`, when they first request a hint that property increments and returns the hint at that index in your hint array on the server.  That way you never have to store a huge array of `isShownToUsers` for each question on your quiz.   The `hasHintAtIndex` property would re-index to 0 whenever the user goes to a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Heres an approach.  Make a mongo collection called `questions` and put documents in it that look like such

```
{
    _id: 156276, 
    ... question stuff... 
    hints: [
        {id: '156276-1', 'text: 'black and white and red all over'}
    ]
}
```

on the `users` mongo collection create a field related to seen hints:

```
{... user stuff ..., seenHints: ['156276-1', '4983049-1']}
```

Then when the user lands on the page you can look up unseen hints for a specific question with a something like

```
var unseenHints = _.filter(question.hints, function(hint) {
    return currentUser.seenHints.indexOf(hint) === -1;
})
```

Comment: But how do I tell which hints belong to which questions? Shouldn't I rather add the hints as an array to each question?

Comment: But can I make sure MongoDB automatically creates unique IDs for each hint?

Comment: you could create your own using some kind of pattern.  You could also use `new Mongo.ObjectID()` to generate one for you.  
But the ids won't be generated automatically unless you make `hints` a separate collection, which you could do as well.  and then just give each hint a `question: ${question._id}` property